# Autodata: document a callable without signature with autodoc-typehints

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'd like to document an attribute of a module which holds a callable, more specifically a type. This attribute is intended to store some type, not be an alias of the type.

When I document the attribute, Sphinx renders the call signature of the type associated with it by default.

[image: Example 1]

I'd like it to simply show the type.

[image: Example 2]

So I did some digging and created this MWE. It seems that it boils down to two factors: using `autodoc-typehints` and having a parameter with a type hint in the class constructor. Taking either one out produces the correct form above.

```
# package.py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, baz: int):
        pass

bar_type = Foo

# documentation
.. currentmodule:: package
.. autoclass:: Foo
.. autodata:: bar_type

# Sphinx conf.py
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx_autodoc_typehints',
]
```

I'm using `autodoc-typehints` because of other reasons, so I'd be hard-pressed to get rid of it. How could I avoid showing the signature in `bar_type`?

Comment: Perhaps this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30542590/407651

Comment: @mzjn At least adding empty parentheses to autodata didn't help.

Comment: But switching to autoclass does the trick, only it has the "alias of" documentation, which I don't like.